# Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xlwt'

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip

I have installed the relevant package.

The ".py" can run successfully when using IDLE. However, when I try to run it in VSCode. It trigger the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xlwt'`.

[image]

Should I modify something in VSCode?

Could any one help to handle this issue?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your pip installs to C:\users[...] and you try to use `python` from D:\Python - which i believe is different environement.

You can change environment in VSCode by pressing `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `P`, write Python and select `Python: Select interpreter`.

The other solution is to install these libs into D:\python by:
`D:/Python/python.exe -m pip install <pack>`.